# How to decrease width of table view cells for iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to create a grouped table view with two sections.  For the first section I would like the width to be only half the screen.  For the second section it would be the standard width.  Also, next to the first section I would like to put a button.

How is this done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put a button in a section what I've done in the past is create a section that has no rows in it. Then, I respond to the **- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section** method with a view that contains a button that is rigged to whatever delegate I need. This will give you the appearance of having a button sitting in a section with no data. This is how buttons appear in the Contacts view/edit screens in the stock iPhone apps.

Table view sections are fixed with to the size of the screen. If you want the individual cells to appear narrower in one section and wider in another, then you can control the size of the view itself with the data source delegate, though you might have to set the background of the table view to transparent so users can actually see the smaller view on top of the table view.